# Get string from ("\n") new line operator

Tags: java

I have an arraylist that containing string like abc"\n"1234,cde"\n"567 fgh"\n"890. I want to get string from where it found new line. like from this array i want only 1234,567 and 890. here is what am doing. but it says "Incompatible Types"
Thanks actually i have show the dialog that containing these contacts.and than if user click on any contacts it opens the dialer activity.

```
 for(String contact: manycontacts){
        String contacts=contact.split("\\r?\\n");
    }
```

Comment: You should add a runable program. Not onl y 3 lines of code.

Comment: @Jens I am not familiar with runable.

Comment: @DevendraSingh runnable in the sense of "something that can be run" (not just a fragment of a program)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`split` returns a `String[]` not a `String`

```
for(String contact: manycontacts){
    String[] contacts=contact.split("\\r?\\n");
}
```

If you need it as one string you have to iterate over the array and concatinate the strings. or use `commons-utils` from apache to join it.

Answer (score 1):

`split` method returns an array of strings `String[]`. In your code, you're returning a simply String. That is the incompatibility.

Simple change it to:

```
 for(String contact: manycontacts){
        String[] contacts=contact.split("\\r?\\n");
 }
```

Answer (score 1):

The split function returns an array of Strings, but you are trying to assign an array of strings to a single string, which throws this error. Rather use:

```
for(String contact: manycontacts){
    String[] contacts=contact.split("\\r?\\n");
    for(String split : contacts) {
       //here you can go on and workt with a single splittet value
    }
}
```

Comment: will this return as abc "new line" 123? or just 123? am guessing it returning like abc in first line and 123 in new line? @Kevin Esche?

Comment: @DevendraSingh What do you mean with new line? Do you want to print them concatinated in a single line?

Comment: Simply i want only the numeric value. not the name, that is on starting indexes of the string. and i want to show a Dialog having only the numbers. not name.

Answer (score 1):

`contact.split()` is returning a String array, not a String, hence the type is incompatible. You'll need

```
String[] contacts = contact.split("\\r?\\n");
```

Answer (score 0):

It is because split returns array of String which will be String[].

Answer (score 0):

simply i used this.to trim the string.

```
 String numberonly = contacts.substring(contact.indexOf('\n'));
```